# Slow Azure Function Processing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I hate this kind of problems when it feels more like esoteric or magic rather than logical IT problem, but it bother me for some time.

I have function app which is hosted on App Service Plan (not Consumption plan).
Inside this function app I have two python functions. One for HttpTrigger and other one for EventGridSubscription events.

When I restart entire app both functions are working great. After some time (1h) when i try to reach exposed endpoint once again, it starts working slowly and I do not receive any kind of response or I have timeouts.

I heard about cold start but I think it's not the case due to App Service Plan.

I also tried change Service Plan offering to more powerful. But it's behave in the same way. I mean, great at the beginning on "fresh" (i hate this term) machine, and slows down after some time.

Any idea what else should be verified?

Comment: Is it with Always On enabled?

Comment: Yes of course it's 'Always on' enabled. I made it sure when I was trying to change App Plan for free tier, then this action is blocked.

Comment: I have no access to your subscription, so it's "of course" to you, not for me.

Comment: Totally, got it:)