# Azure Function connect Azure PostgreSQL ETIMEDOUT, errno: -4039

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, azure-functions

I have an **Azure** (**AZ**) Function does two things:

1. validate submitted info involving 3rd party packages.
2. when ok call a postgreSQL function at AZ to fetch a small set of data

Testing with Postman, this AF localhost response time < 40 ms. Deployed to Cloud, change URL to AZ, same set of data, took **30 seconds** got `Status: 500 Internal Server Error`.

Did a search, thought [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541076/slow-azure-function-processing) might be the case, that I need to bump my subscription to the expensive one to avoid **cold start**.

But more investigation running part 1 and 2 individually and combined, found:

1. validation part alone runs perfect at AZ, response time < 40ms, just like local, suggests cold start/npm-installation is not an issue.
2. pg function call always long and `status: 500` regardless it runs alone or succeeding part 1, no data returned.

`Application Insight` is enabled and added a `Diagnostic settings` with:

- **FunctionAppLogs** and **AllMetrics** selected
- **Send to LogAnalytiscs workspace** and **Stream to an event hub** selected

Following queries found no error/exceptions:

```
requests | order by  timestamp desc |limit 100  // success is "true", time taken 30 seconds, status = 500

traces | order by timestamp desc | limit 30  // success is "true", time taken 30 seconds, status = 500

exceptions | limit 30  // no data returned
```

How complicated my pg call is? Standard connection, simple and short:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './environment/PostgreSql.env'});
const fs = require("fs");
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();    // () = taking default initOptions

require('dotenv').config({ path: './environment/PostgreSql.env'});
const fs = require("fs");
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();    // () = taking default initOptions

db = pgp(
    {
        user: process.env.PGuser,
        host: process.env.PGhost,
        database: process.env.PGdatabase,
        password: process.env.PGpassword,
        port: process.env.PGport,
        ssl: 
            {
                rejectUnauthorized: true,
                ca: fs.readFileSync("./environment/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem").toString(),
            },
    }
);

const pgTest = (nothing) =>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var sql = 'select * from schema.test()';  // test() does a select from a 2-row narrrow table.
        db.any(sql)
        .then
        (
            good => resolve(good),
            bad => reject({status: 555, body: bad})
        )
    }
    );
}

module.exports = { pgTest }
```

AF `test1` is a standard `httpTrigger` anonymous access:

```
const x1 = require("package1");
...
const xx = require("packagex");
const pgdb = require("db");
module.exports = function(context)
{
  try
  {
    pgdb.pgTest(1)
    .then
    ( 
      good => {context.res={body: good}; context.done();},
      bad => {context.res={body: bad}; context.done();}
    )
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
  }
  catch(e)
  { context.res={body: bad}; context.done(); }
}
```

Note:

- AZ = Azure.
- AZ pg doesn't require SSL.
- pg connectivity method: `public access (allowed IP addresses)`
- Postman tests on Local F5 run against the same AZ pg database, all same region.
- `pgAdmin` and `psql` all running fast against the same.
- AF-deploy is zip-file deployment, my understanding it is using the same configuration.
- I'm new to Azure but based on my experience, if it's about credential then should come back right away.

**Update 1**, `FunctionAppLogs | where TimeGenerated between ( datetime(2022-01-21 16:33:20) .. datetime(2022-01-21 16:35:46) )`

[image]

Is it because my pg network access set to `Public access`?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `AZ`? Is that an abbreviation for Azure? Not clear. Also: Are you running your code in the same region as your Postgres instance? Do you have indexing set up? You mentioned always getting an error, so it seems like the 30 seconds is some type of credentials timeout, not a data retrieval timeout, right? Have you verified you can make any connection to your database instance? Can you retrieve anything from any table? Please edit to provide more details.

Comment: You would need to look at the actual query to see why it is slow.

Comment: @jjanes sql `test()` does a select from a 2-row narrrow table.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Correct, `AZ` short for Azure. Same region? Yes, AZ pg location same as Postman and local. Sql `test()` does a select from a 2-row narrrow table, index is unneeded. The returned is always `status: 500`, `Internal Server Error` believed is Postman's interpretation, meanwhile AZ's `Kustov` result is `success=True`, `resultCode=500`, `duration=24,438.526 ...` and `performanceBucket=15sec-30sec`.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Please see supplement note above. If credentials issue should come back right away, shouldn't be timeout. I'm new to Azure, trying to get under the hood of it. :)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Please see **Update 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My AZ pgDB is a flexible server, current `Networking` is `Public access (allowed IP address)`, and I have added some Firewall rule w/ client IP address. My assumption is access is allowed within AZ, but it's not.

**Solution 1**, simply check this box: **Allow public access from any Azure servcie within Azure to this server** at the bottom of the **Settings -> Networking**.

**Solution 2**, find out all AF's outbound IP and add them into Firewall rule, under **Settings -> Networking**. Reason to add them all is Azure select an outbound IP randomly.